# Cannot save APTran record from Custom Graph

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom page, with a custom graph called **POReceiptTieOut**

Data Source:

```
public PXSelect<POReceipt> Document;
```

Form Data Memeber: Document

Grid Data Member: Transactions:

```
public PXSelectJoin<
        APTran,
                LeftJoin<POReceiptLine,
                          On<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr, Equal<APTran.receiptNbr>,
                          And<POReceiptLine.lineNbr, Equal<APTran.receiptLineNbr>>>>,
        Where<APTran.receiptNbr, Equal<Current<POReceipt.receiptNbr>>>> Transactions;
```

I want to be able to update the transaction records in this grid. When I press the standard Save button, I get this error **Error: 'TranDate' cannot be empty.** The APTran.TranDate on all records within my Transactions DAC are present, but for some reason, the save action is not recognizing it.

Here is the code to the POReceiptTieOut graph

```
namespace APPOReceiptTieOut
{
public class POReceiptTieOut : PXGraph<POReceiptTieOut, POReceipt>
{

IPOReceiptRepository _receiptRepository {get;set;}

public POReceiptTieOut()
{
  _receiptRepository = new POReceiptRepository();
}


public PXSelect<POReceipt> Document;

[PXViewName(PX.Objects.AP.Messages.APTran)]
public PXSelectJoin<
        APTran,
                LeftJoin<POReceiptLine,
                          On<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr, Equal<APTran.receiptNbr>,
                          And<POReceiptLine.lineNbr, Equal<APTran.receiptLineNbr>>>>,
        Where<APTran.receiptNbr, Equal<Current<POReceipt.receiptNbr>>>> Transactions;


protected void POReceipt_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
  var row = (POReceipt)e.Row;
  var rowExt = row.GetExtension<POReceiptExt>();
  this.SetCalculatedValues(cache, row);      
}

protected void APTran_CuryLineAmt_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{      
  var row = (APTran)e.Row;      
  POReceipt receipt = Document.Current;
  this.SetCalculatedValues(Document.Cache, receipt);       
}

private void SetCalculatedValues(PXCache cache, object record)
{
  decimal invoiceLineTotal, receiptLineTotal;
  this.CalculateLineTotals(out invoiceLineTotal, out receiptLineTotal);

  cache.SetValueExt<POReceiptExt.usrTranTotal>(record, invoiceLineTotal);
  cache.SetValueExt<POReceiptExt.usrReceiptLineTotal>(record, receiptLineTotal);
  cache.SetValueExt<POReceiptExt.usrBalance>(record, receiptLineTotal - invoiceLineTotal);
  if( Math.Abs(receiptLineTotal  - invoiceLineTotal ) < 10 )
  {
    cache.SetValueExt<POReceipt.status>(record, "B");
  }
  else
  {
    cache.SetValueExt<POReceipt.status>(record, "H");
    cache.SetValueExt<POReceipt.hold>(record, true);
  }   
}

private void CalculateLineTotals(out decimal tranTotal, out decimal lineTotal)
{
    tranTotal = 0;
    lineTotal = 0;
    foreach(PXResult<APTran, POReceiptLine> record in Transactions.Select())
    {
       APTran tran = (APTran)record;
       POReceiptLine rLine = (POReceiptLine)record;
       lineTotal += rLine.TranCostFinal ?? 0; 
       tranTotal += tran.CuryTranAmt ?? 0;        
    }         
}

public bool ValidateReceiptBalance(string receiptNbr)
{      
    POReceipt receipt = _receiptRepository.GetByReceiptNbr(receiptNbr);
    if(receipt == null)
      throw new PXException("Receipt " + receiptNbr + " was not found");      

    this.Document.Current = receipt;

    decimal tranTotal = 0;
    decimal lineTotal = 0;
    this.CalculateLineTotals(out tranTotal, out lineTotal);


    return true;
}

}
}
```

Here is the trace...

5/22/2019 4:38:19 PM Error: 
Error: 'TranDate' cannot be empty. at PX.Data.PXDBDefaultAttribute.RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e) 
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation) 
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistUpdated(Object row, Boolean bypassInterceptor) 
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation) 
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation) 
   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist() 
   at PX.Data.PXSave`1.d__2.MoveNext() 
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__32.MoveNext() 
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__32.MoveNext() 
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.tryExecutePendingCommand(String viewName, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, Object[] searches, Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, Boolean& closeWindowRequired, Int32& adapterStartRow, Int32& adapterTotalRows) 
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)

Comment: You should update your cache using `cache.Update(row/Currentrow);` to notify acumatica that there is a modified data by code. setValue is not enough to notify acumatica that there is changes in the data

Comment: First of all, remove `this.SetCalculatedValues(cache, row);` from `POReceived_RowSelected` event handler. This event handler must be used only for showing/hiding and enabling/disabling UI controls.